# WP All Import plugins configuration for inserting posts?

Tags: php, wordpress, wpallimport

Good day. I'm having a csv file with the structure like this:

```
ID           ArticleID       Title      Content         LanguageID    LanguageCode       Createdby       DateCreated       DateModified
```

Since a post is translated into 2 languages, articleID will be repeated for 2 rows with title and content in different language : e.g

```
   ID           ArticleID       Title               Content         LanguageID    LanguageCode       Createdby       DateCreated       DateModified   
    1              2            Adobe Patches       Adobe System...   0     
    2              2           patchs adobe         système adobe...  1
```

How can I import each record for two languages? If I choose the key value for the plugin to be the articleID, it overrides all the content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using a plugin to handle the translations, such as qTranslate?

If not, personally this is how I would do it (assuming these are WordPress Posts you're adding):

1. Create a meta box in your Posts section with the same main fields, but for the different language.  If you're unfamiliar with how to do this, Advanced Custom Fields will probably be the plugin you would need, since WP ALL Import works great with ACF.   Toolset is also easy to use if you don't like ACF.
2. Modify/Create a new import, and set it to modify ONLY the new Meta box fields for the second language.

That way you'll have all the post data in one place, and the import will work simply.  For reference, you can either have two imports, one for each language, or set WP All Import to handle the filtering (which is more advanced).

Hope that makes sense to you.

Comment: yes, I'm using qTranslate-X and qTranslate-slug for multilanguage. Thanks for your help. :D I'll give it a try.